# Find the maximum number of points per game

Tags: algorithm

The input is an array of cards. In one move, you can remove any group of consecutive identical cards. For removing `k` cards, you get `k * k` points. Find the maximum number of points you can get per game.

Time limit: O(n<sup>4</sup>)
**Example:**
**Input:** [1, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 4, 8, 1]
**Output:** 23

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

To clarify, in the given example, one path to the best solution is

```
Remove   Points   Total   new hand
 3 7s      9        9     [1, 8, 8, 4, 8, 1]
 1 4       1       10     [1, 8, 8, 8, 1]
 3 8s      9       19     [1, 1]
 2 1s      4       23     []
```

Comment: I do not believe your question is complete. For instance - what do you mean by a `game`? How many moves is a game?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should at least present us the approach you have tried so far.

Comment: I think the term *game* is irrelevant here, just consider an array of numbers that shall be reduced to 0 length. @yccteam

Comment: Is it a question from a coding contest ? can you provide a link to the contest ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question with the example @greaf5

Answer (score 1):

**Approach**

Recursion would fit well here.

First, identify the contiguous sequences in the array -- one lemma of this problem is that if you decide to remove at least one `7`, you want to remove the entire sequence of three.  From here on, you'll work with both cards and quantities.  For instance,

```
card  = [1, 8, 7, 8, 4, 8, 1]
quant = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now you're ready for the actual solving.  Iterate through the array.  For each element, remove that element, and add the score for that move. 
Check to see whether the elements on either side match; if so, merge those entries.  Recur on the remaining array.

For instance, here's the first turn of what will prove to be the optimal solution for the given input:

Choose and remove the three 7's

```
card  = [1, 8, 8, 4, 8, 1]
quant = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
score = score + 3*3
```

Merge the adjacent `8` entries:

```
card  = [1, 8, 4, 8, 1]
quant = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Recur on this game.

---

**Improvement**

Use dynamic programming: memoize the solution for every sub game.

Any card that appears only once in the card array can be removed first, without loss of generality.  In the given example, you can remove the 7's and the single 4 to improve the remaining search tree.